# Application compatibility issue

Tags: java, android, xml

I have developed an application in Lollipop, but when I try to run it on Kitkat or lower version, the application stops working. I know applications developed on a specific version cant run on the lower versions. so I tried the following things to make it work.

1. created a new style folder for kitkat i.e, values-v19 and saved a styles.xlm file in it (Code attached).
2. checked my android manifest for sdktarget version and I tried to run on every platform (11-23). in case if it runs.
3. searched all over the net but unfortunately couldnt find any appropriate solutions.

Please help.

I want my application to run on lower versions too.

res/values-v19/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

res/values-v21/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>'
```

android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.draft"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Online_Library"
        android:label="@string/nav_item_library" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LibraryFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_item_library" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: are you use Android Studio, if yes can you post your build.gradle file

Comment: Nope. I am using Eclipse. @KristiyanVarbanov

Comment: @KristiyanVarbanov should i provide you with more code? Do you get my problem? Please help.

Comment: i think the problem comes from build.gradle but you use eclipse... and nothing bring to my mind right now ...